# nodejs v8.11.3 aborts in http2 with TLS if client closes session

Tags: node.js, https, http2

I am hitting an issue with nodejs v8.11.3. I am using http2 with TLS (https) and the server aborts when the client has closed the session. Here is the error:

```
HTTP2 31334: Http2Session server: socket closed
HTTP2 31334: Http2Session server: marking session closed
HTTP2 31334: Http2Session server: submitting goaway
node[31334]: ../src/tls_wrap.cc:604:virtual int node::TLSWrap::DoWrite(node::WriteWrap*, uv_buf_t*, size_t, uv_stream_t*): Assertion `(ssl_) != (nullptr)' failed.
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x8c25db [node]
 3: node::TLSWrap::DoWrite(node::WriteWrap*, uv_buf_t*, unsigned long, uv_stream_s*) [node]
 4: node::http2::Http2Session::SendPendingData() [node]
 5: 0x90e769 [node]
 6: node::Environment::RunAndClearNativeImmediates() [node]
 7: node::Environment::CheckImmediate(uv_check_s*) [node]
 8: 0x141a4ac [node]
 9: uv_run [node]
10: node::Start(uv_loop_s*, int, char const* const*, int, char const* const*) [node]
11: node::Start(int, char**) [node]
12: __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
13: 0x89b1b1 [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What confuses me is why does the server still emit a GOAWAY frame although the socket already was closed?

Does anybody know some quirks to avoid the problem?

Note: the problem does not always happen, but is reproducible as part of a more complex test scenario.

**QUIRK SOLUTION**

See answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quirk to circumvent the problem by monkeypatching "goaway" and introduction an explicit check if the socket has been closed. TypeScript code:

```
const GOAWAY = Symbol();

interface ExtServerHttp2Session extends http2.ServerHttp2Session {
  [GOAWAY]?: (code?: number, lastStreamID?: number, opaqueData?: Buffer | DataView /*| TypedArray*/) => void;
}

function patchedGoaway(
  this: ExtServerHttp2Session,
  code?: number,
  lastStreamID?: number,
  opaqueData?: Buffer | DataView /*| TypedArray*/
): void {
  if (!this.closed) {
    this[GOAWAY]!(code, lastStreamID, opaqueData);
  }
}

function monkeyPatch(session: http2.Http2Session) {
  const extSession = session as ExtServerHttp2Session;
  if (!extSession[GOAWAY]) {
    extSession[GOAWAY] = extSession.goaway;
    extSession.goaway = patchedGoaway;
  }
}
```

Now when handling a new stream, you call `monkeyPatch(stream.session)`.